# Who is the Main Villain in Hearthstone's Curse of Naxxramas?

Tags: hearthstone

In *Curse of Naxxramas* there is an Undead Egyptian-looking guy who pops up from time to time and says things:

- "How did you get in here? You're not supposed to be in here!"
- "Sea Giant?!? Maexxna, that is NOT on my list of approved cards!"
- "Do not distract Faelrina, her job is VERY important, she's training acolytes to worship me."

Who is he? Is he the main villain?

Comment: That would be Kel Thuzad.  Someone else should give an answer with appropriate details (and spelling) though.

Comment: If you are interested, here is his card: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Kel'Thuzad, pretty good remove-spell-magnet IMO, and insane value when u can play him before a large trading.

Comment: @SSilicon Wow he's a really strong card.

Comment: go and play the warcraft III campaigns! NOW!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The guy who pops up is [Kel'Thuzad](http://www.wowwiki.com/Kel'Thuzad), who is an archlich and boss of the Naxxramas necropolis.  The hearthstone addon is based on the dungeon from WoW under the same name:

> Kel'Thuzad was the founder of the Cult of the Damned and one of the principal agents of the Lich King responsible for the spreading of the plague undeath across Lordaeron.

You can find additional information about Kel'Thuzad and Naxxramas from the [wow wiki entry of Naxxramas](http://www.wowwiki.com/Naxxramas).

In hearthstone, you will be able to fight him when the 5th wing (Frostwyrm Lair) unlocks, which also requires you to clear the other 4 wings.

Comment: As a addition, his character's personality in the Warcraft lore is a dark and sinister necromancer. In Hearthstone, hes is a bumbling middle management type, meant to enforce the lighthearted, comical nature of the game.

Answer (score 5):

His name is Kel'Thuzad. He was the last boss in World of Warcraft Naxxramas dungeon as well.